# Running master script file on multiple remote servers without config changes

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, remote-access

I have a master.bat file on Remote Server1 and I want to run it in parallel on 4 remote servers located on same network and having same username and password to login as Server1.
By googling i have explored following methods to do it but having some constraints in my case:

```
1.PsExec tool : psexec \\Server1 C:\master.bat ---- But I am not allowed to install PsExec tool for security reasons.
2.Powershell : Invoke-Command -ComputerName $client -ScriptBlock { cd C:\master.bat} -Credential $(Get-Credential) -Authentication CredSSP ----But I have to enable PS Remoting (WinRM) on every remote machine on whom I need to execute scripts using PowerShell, for which I am not allowed.
```

Is there any other way to run **master.bat** or **master.ps1** on 4 remote servers??

**And also if I am not mistaken....**

```
1.Installing PsExec tool has security drawbacks...??
2.Enabling PS Remoting (WinRM) also has chances of security threats...??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create scheduled tasks on the servers that you want to run the .bat file, and then use schtasks.exe to run the tasks on demand.

You can also set up WINRM to only provide a constrained PS session that can only be used to run that .bat file, using credentials stored in the session config to eliminate the need for credential delegation.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/27/an-introduction-to-powershell-remoting-part-five-constrained-powershell-endpoints.aspx

Comment: Could you please elaborate as that link is not accessible to me ?

Comment: The link is to a article describing how to create and register a custom session configuration.  There's more information there than I can reproduce here.  Run Get-Help *PSSessionConfiguration  and Get-Help about_PSSessions and review the available help to get an idea of what's involved.